# How to see people who liked a public post in Instagram?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

If I see any public profile, once I liked it, I want to know list of users who liked that photo or video.

Note : I am using Instagram in system browser not as a mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to view users who have liked a post on Instagram website, it was possible a while back, but its disabled now.

You can use some 3rd party apps that use API to view likers, but this is limited to latest 120 likers.

You can view all using the Instagram app

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can
Once, you got the public_content permission from the user.
You might call the endpoint

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

However, public_content permission only works after your application got approved. Alternatively, you may add sandbox user to try out.